# hide nth child items after multiple of 7

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I have items set out from a cms and no control over their number.

I want to use css to hide all items over a multiple of 7, but only the last few.

I.e. if there are 10 items I need to hide the last 3, if there are 22 items I need to hide the last one... (the remainder after dividing by 7).

I've tried a combination of nth child and nth last child, but haven't got close!

Comment: Not sure if that is actually possible. General "quantity queries" that work based on a _fixed_ number of elements can be created with a bit of trickery (https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css/), but what you want here, is basically some sort of "modulo" functionality, and I don't see how that could be implemented, using what CSS has to offer today.

Comment: Generating a "set" of such quantity queries upfront, up to a maximum number of items you need to cover, might be a possibility though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cover a lot of cases. To be more precise, you have 6 different cases based on the position of the `(7n + 1)` item.

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (event) => {box.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))});
```

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7,1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.box div {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(1),
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(2),
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(2) ~ *,
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(3),
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(3) ~ *,
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(4),
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(4) ~ *,
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(5),
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(5) ~ *,
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(6),
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(6) ~ * {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<button>add item</button>
```

You can optimize like below:

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (event) => {box.appendChild(document.createElement("div"))});
```

```css
.box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7,1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.box div {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(-n + 6),
.box :nth-child(7n + 1):nth-last-child(-n + 6) ~ * {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<button>add item</button>
```

Comment: haha - I cracked it just as you helpfully wrote your answer - and yes - exactly the same approach I ended up with (see my answer below). Thank you so much :)
EDIT - actually similar approach, but not exactly the same - I got it down to one single selection

Comment: @AdamStrags your selector doesn't cover all the cases, ex: https://jsfiddle.net/0nyvh9ed/

Comment: thank you! good shout - adjusted below :)

Answer (score 0):

Sussed - useful for anyone else...

```css
li:nth-last-child(-n + 8) + li:nth-child(7n) ~ li{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```